# knockout js pushes the same data twice into my observable array, why?

Tags: knockout.js

This is my code that collects data from a socket call, turns it into an observable and pushes it into an observable array.

```
model.friendHasJoined = ko.computed(function () {

    socket.on('friend joined', function(data) {


        var mapping = {
            'friendsOnline': {
                create: function(options) {
                    return new friendModel(options.data);
                }
            }
        };

        model.friendsOnline.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping));

       // console.log(ray);

        console.log(model.friendsOnline())

    });

});
```

I noticed that when I push the observable data into the array, the raw data I get is also pushed into the array, making it two items in the array and I just want the observable one, why is this ?

Answer (score 0):

A function passed to a `ko.computed` is executed immediately, and whenever one of its dependencies changes. If the function has a side effect, such as the attachment of your `socket.on` callback, this can be a problem. If it happens to, for some reason, run twice, you'll end up with two attached callbacks causing duplicate data to enter your observable array.

I can't exactly figure out if this is what's actually happening, but my advice would be to remove the `ko.computed` wrapper and see if the problem still persists.

Comment: are u saying i can use a socket directly in a model class ?

Comment: I'd expect something like `model.socketConnection = socket.on("friend joined", model.addFriend)` in which `model.addFriend` is the function you've already written.

Comment: woow, i didnt know this was possible atol, thanks alot i will try it Today